How to add data with Pyinstaller?
Im trying to pack a bunch of files to exe with Pyinstaller but getting this error msg
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI172082\bip_utils\bip\bip39\wordlist/chinese_simplified.txt'
[27888] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

this is my Pyinstaller command rn
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "gen" --hidden-import "utils" --hidden-import "notifier" --add-binary "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/coincurve/libsecp256k1.dll;coincurve" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/chinese_simplified.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/chinese_traditional.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/czech.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/english.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/french.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/italian.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/korean.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/portuguese.txt;bip_utils" --add-data "C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/bip_utils/bip/bip39/wordlist/spanish.txt;bip_utils"  "C:/Users/jakub/Desktop/walletthing/main.py"

I tried adding it differently or adding diff names after the path to the wordlists I need imported with bip_utils but to no avail got the same issue with the dll I added as binary but right now it isnt working for the bip_utils txt files
